# Syntax error: integer expression expected

Tags: bash, integer

I've tried Googling a lot I am still not able to find solution

```
rm -y zoznam
tomatch=1000000000
treshold=10
okvalue=`expr "$tomatch" / 100 * "$treshold"`

while read hostname sum size znak
do
        while [ "$tomatch" -gt "$okvalue" ]
        do
                if [ "$tomatch" -gt "$size" ]
                then
                echo $hostname >> zoznam
                tomatch=`expr "$tomatch" - "$size"`
                fi
        done

done < weeklysize
```

I get line 8: [: : integer expression expected
please help

Comment: What value does `$okvalue` have? It seems to me that it is not an integer.

Comment: Add to the top of your shell script `set -xv`. This will turn on debugging, and will help you see what values are in your `if` statement. I suspect that `$size` is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use `expr` for arithmetic, unless you are using an archaic shell:

```
okvalue=$(( $tomatch / 100 * $treshold ))
```

This will avoid your actual problem of needing to escape `*`, as well as avoiding the need to spawn an external program.

Similarly, you can increment `tomatch` with

```
: $(( tomatch += $size ))
```

( or simply `(( $tomatch += $size ))` to use a `bash` arithmetic command ).

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `*` in `okvalue`s assignment:

```
okvalue=`expr "$tomatch" / 100 \* "$treshold"`
```

You could alternatively evaluate the expression using `bc`

```
okvalue=$(echo "$tomatch / 100 * $treshold" | bc)
```

If you are using bash, you could instead do:

```
okvalue=$(bc <<<"$tomatch / 100 * $treshold")
```

Or even just:

```
okvalue=$((tomatch / 100 * treshold))
```

You don't need the `$` inside the `(( ))` as explained [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html)

For sake of completeness, I will also mention `let`, which is also mentioned in the above link:

```
let okvalue="tomatch / 100 * treshold"
```